# When debugging website in Visual Studio, Directory Listing --/ is shown instead of default page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have an asp.net website set up on my localhost on port 88 using IIS(IIS 7.5), it works fine when I navigate to http://localhost:88/default.asp but when I attempt to debug this website using the debug tool in Visual Studio(Visual Studio 2012) I get a  Directory Listing --/ with the contents of the source folder of the website listed.
[image: Directory listing error]
When one of the script is then clicked a further Server Error in '/' Application  occurs. [image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nQi0.jpg)

I have tried rebuilding the whole solution and enabled server side and client side debugging in IIS to no avail. The website makes use of a COM application, however I don't think that's where the issue is as the website works when I navigate to http://localhost:88/default.asp. I'm at a loss on what to do next to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to start without debugging and then attach to the process?

Comment: yes I have but my breakpoints do not work when I try this. I get a "“The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that Visual Studio is loading localhost:55285 means that it is configured to debug using the Visual Studio development server, not IIS. It seems like you're better off debugging with IIS instead.

To do that, in Visual Studio:

1. Open the Project menu
2. Click '[project name] Properties' (second from bottom)
3. Click 'Web' on the left
4. Select 'Use Local IIS Web Server'
5. For 'Project URL' put "http://localhost:88"
6. Save, then try debugging again.

Comment: This works but I have a "“The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” error which I thought I could avoid by using this method.

Comment: That can happen if IIS and Visual Studio are reading different versions of your application.Is the IIS site reading from the same folder that Visual Studio is loading the project from?

Comment: Then try Build -> Clean Solution, then Build -> Build Solution, and try again. It might help. Don't use Rebuild Solution. I have found that it does not quite do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Try to Build the application In Debug Mode and give a try.